# Prove that this is a valid formula using axioms of propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The question is how to prove using basic axioms this expression:

$$(A \to B) \to ((\lnot C \to A) \to (\lnot C \to B))$$

I have the list of axioms, one of them looks like this: $A \to (B \to A)...$ But I don't understand how to apply this to my expression...

Comment: What exactly *are* your basic axioms? Without knowing those, we can't really help.

Comment: The are all listed here, I can use at least first 7 of them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Alternative_calculus

Comment: I suggest reading a proof of the deduction theorem.  Then write your proof using the deduction theorem.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first prove Hypothetical Syllogism ($\{A \rightarrow B, B \rightarrow C \} \vDash A \rightarrow C$ as a Lemma:

1. $A \rightarrow B$ Premise
2. $B \rightarrow C$ Premise
3. $(B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow  (A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C))$ Axiom 1
4. $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$ MP 2,3
5. $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$  Axiom 2
6. $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$ MP 4,5
7. $A \rightarrow C$ MP 1,6

Of course, $A$, $B$, and $C$ can be any statement here, so this means that you can infer any statement of the form $\varphi \rightarrow \gamma$ from two statements $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ and $\psi \rightarrow \gamma$. Let's call this Lemma HS, and use it to get your desired result:

1. $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\neg C \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B))$  Axiom 1
2. $(\neg C \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)) \rightarrow ((\neg C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (\neg C \rightarrow B))$ Axiom 2
3. $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((\neg C \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (\neg C \rightarrow B))$  HS 1,2

Note you are only using Axioms 1 and 2 since this is all about conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a premised proof:

$$\begin{array} {rl}
   \text{Premise} :& A \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{Premise} :& \lnot C \Rightarrow A
\\ \text{Premise} :& \lnot C
\\ \text{MP}      :& A
\\ \text{MP}      :& B
\end{array}$$

Then apply deduction theorem:

$$\begin{array} {rl}
   \text{Ax 1}    :& (A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{Ax 2}    :& (\lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{Premise} :& A \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{Premise} :& \lnot C \Rightarrow A
\\ \text{MP}      :& \lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{MP}      :& (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{MP}      :& \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\end{array}$$

Then apply deduction theorem again:

$$\begin{array} {rl}
   \text{Ax 1}    :& (A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{Ax 2}    :& (\lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{Premise} :& A \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{MP}      :& \lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{MP}      :& (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\end{array}$$

Then apply deduction theorem again:

$$\begin{array} {rl}
\\ \text{Ax 2}    :& (\lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow
\\                 & (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow
\\                 & \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{Ax 1}    :& ((\lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow 
\\                 & (A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow 
\\                 & (\lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{MP}      :& (A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{Ax 2}    :& ((A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow
\\                 &  ((A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow 
\\                 & (A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{MP}      :& ((A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{Ax 1}    :& (A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow B
\\ \text{MP}      :& (A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\lnot C \Rightarrow A) \Rightarrow \lnot C \Rightarrow B
\end{array}$$